# How to allow Thunderbird to receive local mail (from apps to the user/root) while in offline mode?

Tags: security, email, thunderbird

I'd like to have Thunderbird running on Debian10/KDE in Offline mode (mostly for security and privacy purposes but also to not receive any other mails) but still be able to receive mails to the user or root from processes / apps running on the machine (e.g. for popup KDE notifications about system events like cronjob-scan-results, intrusion-attempts, file-monitoring etc).

Is that possible (how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround was to create a new Thunderbird profile like [described here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-thunderbird-profiles).

Then one can read the root@localhost mails with Thunderbird after setting the account up (without entering the root password into Thunderbird) like [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-do-i-read-local-email-in-thunderbird).

This doesn't work if Thunderbird is in Offline mode but still keeps it fairly isolated (or does it?) from other profiles/accounts and I created an issue (an enhancement request) for a proper solution [**here**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1734981).

Answer (score 1):

No. Thunderbird has no interface for a local delivery agent.

You could write directly to thunderbird's mail storage (it's in a common format), but that would break logic state of the application.

In short, if you want a thunderbird that only receives messages from a single source, then

1. that source needs to be a mail server AND
2. you can just set up dedicated isolated thunderbird profiles where that is the only configured server.

Popups are completely orthogonal to the question of receiving emails (unless you write a notification daemon that converts popups to emails, and sends them to a mail server).